# Unable to create documents : code 11000 in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing a user sign in system using Node/Express.js

I have this code in `userSchema`:

```
email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate(value: string) {
        if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
          throw new Error("Invalid email!");
        }
      },
    },
```

When I create a new user (for the first time), with no `email` field it is created successfully.

Now, when I try to create another user with also doesn't have an `email` I get this error :

```
"error": {
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "email": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "email": null
        }
    },
```

I haven't set any `unique` attribute to `email`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `email` field saves `null` on the first time. The validation doesn't return it. So, when you run it for the second time `11000` for duplicate key meaning `null`. You might have set email as the primary key for the documents.

You can do something like this:

```
    email: {
      type: String,
      validate: {
        validator: async function(email) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                // throw new Error("Invalid email!"); // instead of throwing error return false 
                return false;
              } else {
                  return true;
              }
        },
      },
    }
```

Comment: I still get the error

Comment: Can you show me what email are you adding?  Is the error same?

Comment: I'm not even adding an email, I've set unique to false

Comment: Also removed validation

Comment: You should remove all the documents from the DB and then start to add new one.

Comment: That's what I tried

Comment: check [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/mongodb-error-code-11000/) link.